# Programmatically Add Outlook Room Calanders to Users Calendars View Shortcuts

Tags: vb.net, outlook, calendar, office-addins

I am looking for a way to add multiple Room calendars to a User in Outlook 2016.  The process I am trying to replicate is:

Click on Calendar View > Folder Ribbon > Add Calendar > From Room List > (Select Room) > Click OK

This places the Room Calendar on the left side of Outlook under "Rooms" which the user can then view.

We are a small firm, there are only 8 rooms available and everyone needs to be able to see them without having to add them manually one by one, or worse, phone me to do it.

I primarily code in VB but happy to take code in C# and convert it.

I have tried using GetSharedDefaultCalendarmy(Recipient, olFolderCalendar) in which I was successful in mapping a standard users shared calendar, but the same process against Room calendars does not work.

Any advice and examples welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: "happy to take code in C " Do you mean C#?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, C#